# Referenciar classe Sintaxe Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma classe onde tenho salvo uma chave de configuração sendo chave e valor, porém preciso pegar o valor dessa chave e passar para minha página `cshtml`. Estou tendo dificuldade com isso.

Já passei o caminho da classe, porém não consigo referenciar para trazer o valor da chave. Preciso trazer e valor da chave para poder fazer uma lógica simples em cima desse valor.

Tenho uma classe de configuração das chaves que ficam salvas: (chave é ReportServer)

```
public static string ReportServer
{
    get { return InstanceResolverFor<IConfigurationSource>.Instance.Read("ReportServer"); }
}
```

Tenho minha página `cshtml` onde tem essa sintaxe razor:

```
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/js/app/FIDC/index.js")
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        if (Model.Erro)
        {
            <script>
                modal.exibir("Ops", "@Model.MensagemErro", modal.tipoModal.Erro);
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                modal.exibir("Ok", "@Model.MensagemSucesso", modal.tipoModal.Sucesso);
            </script>
        }
    } 
}
```

Tenho Minha classe negócio: (estou pegando o valor da minha chave através do `config.ReportServer`)

```
 var serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;
 serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://CCD-APPBI-001:80/ReportServer");
 serverReport.ReportPath = string.Concat("/", config.ReportServer, "/",relatorio);
```

Agora eu preciso pegar o valor dessa chave `ReportServer` para meu html, onde tenho duas tags abaixo:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://ccd-appbi-001/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fRelatoriosClientes%2fcessao_polo&SelectedSubTabId=GenericPropertiesTab&SelectedTabId=ViewTab;rs:Command=Render">Abrir</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://ccd-appbi-001/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fRelatoriosClientes%2fsabemi&SelectedSubTabId=ReportDataSourcePropertiesTab&SelectedTabId=ViewTab">Abrir</a>
```

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução bem ad-hoc e fortemente tipada seria **usar tuplas para passar mais de um valor** para a view cshtml:

**Exemplo** - vou passar 2 dados para o CSHTML (o view model e uma string representando a chave):

Na view faça assim:

```
@model Tuple<MinhaClasse, string>

<p><strong>Nome:</strong> @Model.Item1.Nome<p>
<p><strong>Chave:</strong> @Model.Item2<p>
```

E no controller:

```
public ActionResult Metodo()
{
    MinhaClasse viewModel = ...; // esse é o seu View-Model
    string chave = ...; // essa é a chave que quer passar pra view

    return this.View(Tuple.Create(
        viewModel,
        chave
      ));
}
```

**Outras formas**

Se quiser uma forma mais encapsulada, recomendo criar uma class de view-model que contenha em si todos os dados para aquela view específica... assim não precisaria usar Tuple.

Ainda há uma outra foram ainda mais encapsulada caso deseje passar um certo dado para todas as views, ou pelo menos para a maioria das views: extender a classe `WebViewPage`... mas ai é bem mais trabalhoso, realmente é o oposto de uma solução ad-hoc como a tupla.

Se for um caso mais elaborado manda um comentário que eu amplio a resposta de acordo.

Comment: Obrigado Miguel, porem o meu problema é que a chave ja tem um valor que fica salva num banco nosql que mora dentro da minha aplicação,
Resumindo: em Homologacao a chave vai aponta relatorios para homologacao e Produção a chave vai aponta relatorio para produção.

Comment: Então. Você conecta no banco no-sql, carrega a chave na variável `chave` e passa ela para a view cshtml da forma que indiquei.

Comment: Geralmente toda a lógica de fazer consultas ao banco de dados fica no controller, exatamente para que a view seja apenas uma camada símples de visualização.

Comment: Mudei de ideia. Vou responder, porque o questionamento agora é completamente diferente.

Answer (score 4):

Vou ensinar dois métodos mais sofisticados para obter valores fortemente tipados na sua *View*.

## Método 1: Derivando [`System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage(v=vs.118).aspx)

Crie algo assim:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Infrastructure.ViewPages
{
    public abstract class MinhaWebViewPage : WebViewPage
    {
        public string ReportServer { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class MinhaWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
    {
        public string ReportServer { get { return // defina o valor aqui } }
    }
}
```

Em `Views/Web.config` (não o do diretório raiz), altere o seguinte:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <!--<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">-->
  <pages pageBaseType="SeuProjeto.Infrastructure.ViewPages.MinhaWebViewPage">
    ...
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Feche suas *Views* e reabra. Você verá que `@ReportServer` poderá ser adicionada à sua *View* sem erros.

## Método 2: Estendendo [`System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage(v=vs.118).aspx)

Crie algo assim:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Infrastructure.Extensions
{
    public static class WebViewPageExtensions
    {
        public string ReportServer(this System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage webViewPage)
        {
            return // retorne seu valor aqui
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
@this.ReportServer()
```

Comment: No seu método 1, ainda é possível ao invés de usar o Web.config + diretiva @model, usar a diretiva @inherit do razor indicando a classe `MinhaWebViewPage<TModel>`. Tornando a solução específica por arquivo, caso seja de interesse do OP.